# Is it possible to wp_redirect() to a new tab?

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

Is it at all possible to set up `wp_redirect()` so that it redirects to a new browser tab? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Nop, its not possible at all with `wp_redirect()`. One have to find other way around to accomplish it.

Comment: @M-R This is the right answer. Why don't you post it as a reply ?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nop, its not possible at all with `wp_redirect()`. One have to find other way around to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just add a form with a target of _blank?
e.g.

```
<form action="myfile.php" target="_blank" method="">
    <input type="submit" value="Go There" />
</form>
```

Would that not work?

Comment: ?? I would have thought this would be the answer you were looking for, to open a link in a new tab?

Also you could do:

`<a href="myfile.php" target="_blank">link</a>`

Comment: Also, just to point out - if this is the answer that you are looking for, then this question shouldn't really have been on wordpress.stackexhance but rather on stackoverflow